# Python regular expression to strip script tags

Tags: python, regex

I'm a little scared to ask this for fear of retribution from the SO "You can't parse HTML with regular expressions" cult. Why does `re.subn(r'<(script).*?</\1>', '', data, re.DOTALL)` not strip the multiline 'script' but only the two single-line ones at the end, please?

Thanks, HC

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """\
<nothtml> 
  <head> 
    <title>Regular Expression HOWTO &mdash; Python v2.7.1 documentation</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = {
        URL_ROOT:    '../',
        VERSION:     '2.7.1',
        COLLAPSE_MODINDEX: false,
        FILE_SUFFIX: '.html',
        HAS_SOURCE:  true
      };
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_static/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_static/doctools.js"></script>
"""

>>> print (re.subn(r'<(script).*?</\1>', '', data, re.DOTALL)[0])
<nothtml> 
  <head> 
    <title>Regular Expression HOWTO &mdash; Python v2.7.1 documentation</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = {
        URL_ROOT:    '../',
        VERSION:     '2.7.1',
        COLLAPSE_MODINDEX: false,
        FILE_SUFFIX: '.html',
        HAS_SOURCE:  true
      };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving aside the question of whether this is a good idea in general, the problem with your example is that the [fourth parameter to `re.subn` is `count`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.subn) - there's no `flags` parameter in Python 2.6, although it was introduced as a fifth parameter in Python 2.7.  Instead you can add `(?s) to the end of your regular expression for the same effect:

```
>>> print (re.subn(r'<(script).*?</\1>(?s)', '', data)[0])

<nothtml> 
  <head> 
    <title>Regular Expression HOWTO &mdash; Python v2.7.1 documentation</title> 




>>>
```

... or if you're using Python 2.7, this should work:

```
>>> print (re.subn(r'<(script).*?</\1>(?s)', '', 0, data)[0])
```

... i.e. inserting `0` as the `count` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I just don't get why one should parse the HTML for this bit of substitution.

Comment: @hc: I suppose it's somewhat debatable with a very simple example like this, particularly since we don't know the what context is of the larger problem that you're trying to solve.  However, I've added an extra answer with some different approaches, since I think they're easier as well as safer.

Comment: @hc: Just found this. The reason people vote against regex is that there are so many creative ways to inject script tags that it's simply not worth trying to figure out the correct regexp. It's bound to be long and complex.

Comment: Are you sure that the `(?s)` inline modifier must not be inserted before the dot?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: it can come anywhere in the regular expression - the [documentation says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), "The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: [...], *for the entire regular expression*." (my emphasis)

Comment: @MarkLongair: indeed. It's a strange behaviour (other regex flavors begin to apply the modifier after the point where it is inserted), but it is more understandable if you consider that `(?-s)` doesn't exist in Python.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: yeah, I confess that my first reaction on seeing your comment was "how does my answer work at all?!" since I've been using other languages with the other convention more recently... :)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it's of interest, I thought I'd add an additional answer showing two ways of doing this with [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/index.html), which I've found very nice for parsing HTML.  (lxml is [one of the alternatives that the author of BeautifulSoup suggests](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html), in light of the problems with the most recent version of the latter library.)

The point of adding the first example is that it's really very simple and should be much more robust than using a regular expression to remove the tags.  In addition, if you want to do any more complex processing of the document, or if the HTML you're parsing is malformed, you have a valid document tree that you can manipulate programmatically.

#### Remove all script tags

This example is based on [the HTMLParser example from lxml's documentation](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html#parsing-html):

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

broken_html = '''
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Regular Expression HOWTO &mdash; Python v2.7.1 documentation</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = {
        URL_ROOT:    '../',
        VERSION:     '2.7.1',
        COLLAPSE_MODINDEX: false,
        FILE_SUFFIX: '.html',
        HAS_SOURCE:  true
      };
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_static/jquery.js"></script>
'''

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(broken_html), parser)

for s in tree.xpath('//script'):
    s.getparent().remove(s)

print etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), pretty_print=True)
```

That produces this output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Regular Expression HOWTO &#8212; Python v2.7.1 documentation</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

#### Use lxml's Cleaner module

On the other hand, since it looks as if you're trying to remove awkward tags like `<script>` perhaps the [Cleaner](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html) module from lxml will also do other things you'd like:

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

broken_html = '''
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Regular Expression HOWTO &mdash; Python v2.7.1 documentation</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = {
        URL_ROOT:    '../',
        VERSION:     '2.7.1',
        COLLAPSE_MODINDEX: false,
        FILE_SUFFIX: '.html',
        HAS_SOURCE:  true
      };
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_static/jquery.js"></script>
'''

cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure=False)
print cleaner.clean_html(broken_html)
```

... which produces the output:

```
<html><head><title>Regular Expression HOWTO — Python v2.7.1 documentation</title></head></html>
```

(n.b. I've changed `nothtml` in your example to `html` - with your original, method 1 works fine, but wraps everything in `<html><body>`, but method 2 doesn't work for reasons I don't have time to figure out right now :))

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove html, style and script tages, you can use re.

```
def stripTags(text):
  # scripts = re.compile(r'<script.*?/script>')
  scripts = re.compile(r'<(script).*?</\1>(?s)')
  css = re.compile(r'<style.*?/style>')
  tags = re.compile(r'<.*?>')

  text = scripts.sub('', text)
  text = css.sub('', text)
  text = tags.sub('', text)
```

I can work easily

Comment: The first line that is commented out can be written in this way if it makes more sense?  

`scripts = re.compile(r'<script[. \S\s]*?/script>')`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, is don't do that.  Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or elementree to get rid of them.  Parse your data as HTML or XML.  Regular expressions won't work and are the wrong answer to this problem.

Comment: This.  Beautiful Soup is a lovely library.  Makes scraping incredibly easy.

Comment: Sorry, but this just amounts to another cult answer :) and does not address 'why'. Glancing at the Soup there are statements such as re.compile('(<[^<>]*)/>') Are they heretics, too?

Comment: the main reason for not using regular expression is nested tags.

Comment: @hc - It isn't a 'cult' answer.  It's a true answer.  The reason is nested tags, as someone pointed out.